# Unable to install tweepy on anaconda

Tags: python, installation, package, anaconda, tweepy

Hi ive been trying to install Tweepy but it doea not install on my anaconda prompt this is the command I enter

'''   conda install -c conda-forge tweepy'''

the message I get back is

'''[WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
()'''

Comment: Could you post the full error? or this is it? and also if you can specify the python/conda versoins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these commands too-

1. conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf201901" tweepy
2. conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" tweepy

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running the command prompt as administrator and execute the conda command.

If that doesn't work, you might have to try running it on WSL/WSL2 in your Win machine.